# Deriving green function for Biharmonic equation and more in general polyharmonic.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function, derivation-of-formulae

As I am not an expert on biharmonic and more in general polyharmonic equation. Is there a procedure similar to the one highlighted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4709165/evans-partial-differential-equations-derivation-of-green-function) to derive the green function?

Some people however don't seem to follow that procedure to define what a Green function is.
Many seem to simply define it as the solution of

$$
LG(x,y) = \delta(x - y)
$$

where $L$ is any linear differential operator. I can have an intuition why defining the Green function as above make sense. Suppose indeed we want to solve a problem of the form

$$
Lu = f
$$

And suppose $G$ is the Green function, defined earlier. Assuming we're working with distributions We then have
$$
Lu = f = f * \delta = f * LG = L(f*G)
$$
which yields
$$
Lu = L(f*G) \Rightarrow Lu - L(f*G) = L(u - f*G) = 0
$$
therefore if $u - f*G = \Phi$ (the fundamental solution for the operator $L$ then we have
$$
u = \Phi + f*G.
$$
Which would be the solution. In the link I gave the derivation is taken from Evans - Partial Differential Equations and it seems a bit more involved since it also takes into account boundary conditions to be applied.

Assuming the math I did in this post is correct is there a reason why Evans prefers to follow a different method for his derivation?

If the math I did is wrong what is the right way to derive the Green function for at least $L = \Delta^2$ or more in general $L = \Delta^k$?

Comment: You hesitate between a "green function", a function that doesn't use chemicals on its domain ? :) and a "Green function"...

Comment: I wrote the question while working hopefully there're no too many mistakes ...my apologies

Comment: I was kidding, you have understood it.